# Сортировка div на jQuery

Tags: jquery, сортировка, javascript

Здравствуйте всем, перерыл весь интернет, но подобной сортировки не нашел. Все которые удалось найти работают очень криво или вообще не работают. Есть код

```
        <select id="ids">
        <option value="#" selected>все</option>
        <option value="id1" >id1</option>
        <option value="id2" >id2</option>
        <option value="id3" >id3</option>
        <option value="id4" >id4</option>
        </select>

    <select id="langs">
    <option value="#" selected>все</option>
    <option value="lang1" >lang1</option>
    <option value="lang2" >lang2</option>
    <option value="lang3" >lang3</option>
    <option value="lang4" >lang4</option>
    </select>

    <select id="procs">
    <option value="#" selected>все</option>
    <option value="proc1" >proc1</option>
    <option value="proc2" >proc2</option>
    <option value="proc3" >proc3</option>
    <option value="proc4" >proc4</option>
    </select>

                <div id='d-contents'>

                <div class="id1 lang3 proc2"> <a href="###" ><img src="###.jpg"/></a> <a href="###">Зоголовок</a> <div>текст</div></div>

            <div class="id2 lang2 proc4"> <a href="###" ><img src="###.jpg"/></a> <a href="###">Зоголовок</a> <div>текст</div></div>

            <div class="id3 lang1 proc4"> <a href="###" ><img src="###.jpg"/></a> <a href="###">Зоголовок</a> <div>текст</div></div>

и еще сотня подобных дивов с разными параметрами в class...
            </div>
```

может кто подскажет как реализовать сортировку div элементов в зависимости от выбора select-ов, чтобы изначально на странице были все дивы, но если выбрать например в select id="ids" option value="id3" то на странице остались бы только те div в классе которых есть id3, думаю понятно, желательно, чтобы селекты не мешали друг другу. Если кто поможет , большое спасибо.

Comment: Вы не спутали случайно сортировку и фильтрацию?

Answer (score 3):

Что-то вроде

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('select').change(function()
    {
        $('#d-contents div').hide();
        $('.' + $(this).val()).show();
    });
});
```

Дальше сами, пропишите условие на случай если отображать все.

З.Ы. и в div'ах лучше сделать не `<div>текст</div> а <p>текст</p> или <span>текст</span>`

Comment: Но только наверное надо show делать с

    $('#d-contents div.' + $(this).val()).show();

Answer (score 2):

В странных местах вы инет рыли :-)

```
$('select').change(function(){
    var class_name = $(this).val();
    $('#d-contents div').each(function(){

    if($(this).hasClass(class_name))
        $(this).show();
    else
        $(this).hide();
   });
});
```

Comment: Спасибо Ваш пример, пока самый рабочий, единственное, если выбрать id1 а в другом селекте lang1 то на странице будут все дивы с lang1 и перестанет учитываться выбор id1 в первом селекте - это возможно исправить?

Comment: Конечно, это Вам надо добавить значение селектов других к проверки классов:

    var class_name1 = $('#select1'/*выборка для нахождения нужных селектов*/).val()
    ...
    var cass_name2 = ... 
    ...
    if($(this).hasClass(class_name1) or     $(this).hasClass(class_name2))
   ...

Comment: А как код будет выглядеть полностью? А то я в программировании вообще ничего не понимаю.

Comment: :-D Код за Вас бесплатно писать не буду :-) на мой взгляд моих объяснений достаточно чтобы изменить код как надо, даже без знаний программирования. Готов поспособствовать в комментариях в ответы на Ваши вопросы чтобы Вы сами решили Вашу задачу.

Comment: Чад, напишите тут или на werty1001собакаяндекс.ru как с вами можно связаться, чтобы дописать код.

Answer (score 2):

Вот [полное решение](http://jsfiddle.net/zhukovroman/qWGQb/) (я немного подправил структуру HTML, думаю, что вы без труда поставите нужные селекторы потом).

Comment: Спасибо, но при пробе, когда выбрал селект - страница стала абсолютно пустая, видимо скрылись все дивы на странице сразу.